# Solving a logarithmic equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**The [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWUn2.jpg):**

> $$\frac{\ln{x}}{2}=(\ln x)^2-3$$

I'm a 12th grader a 4 points math student and I have an exam tommorrow (Math). I am trying to solve a question but unfortunately I'm not able to, it's supposed to be an easy one, but it seems it's the opposite for me.

I'm sorry but the only way that I can upload the question is attaching a picture because I'm on a phone and I'm really in a hurry.

Comment: set $t=\ln(x)$ and solve a quadratic equation

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :) , Thanks a lot .

Comment: then it's not a quadratic. ln(x) = 4ln(x) + 6,   ln(x) = -2. It's linear

Comment: So confusing! Which of the two?

Comment: Last question. Do you mean $$\frac{\ln x}{2}=(\ln x)^2-3$$ or $$\frac{\ln x}{2}=\ln (x^2)-3?$$

Comment: To confirm it's the one on the top.

Comment: Okay,lets edit your post and my answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem .** How to solve $\frac{\ln x}{2}=(\ln x)^2-3$?

**Solution.**

Let $t=\ln x$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\ln x}{2}=(\ln x)^2-3&\implies \frac{t}{2}=t^2-3\\
&\implies 2t^2-t-6=0\\
&\implies (2t+3)(t-2)=0\\
&\implies t=-\frac{3}{2}\text{ or }t=2
\end{align}$$
The answer is $x=e^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ or $x=e^2$.

Comment: misread the question. no marks. High school maths sucks doesn't it?

Comment: @gebra Do I still misread the question?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This was an answer to the original question, which had $\ln(x^2)$ where it now reads $(\ln x )^2$.

I think the best way to attack this problem is to note/remember that
$$
\ln(x^2) = 2\ln(x).
$$
That turns the original question into a simple linear equation in the variable $\ln(x)$. Solve that, then exponentiate.

PS In a hurry on the telephone probably isn't the best way to study for an exam tomorrow.

Comment: That is correct .. But school is putting us in a lot of pressure .